# Grab a filename in a directory using batch script

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, for-loop

I want to import a table with filename *.sql. I'm trying to use for loop with this but it doesn't seem to work. Here's my code:

```
cd C:\path_to_dumped_table
FOR /F %%G IN (*.sql) DO (
mysql -h [host] -u[uname] database < C:\path_to_dumped_table\%%G
)
```

Anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lose the `/F` flag.  What you want is a plain `FOR %%G IN (...` command.